# Symfony2 : Handling error on a single controller

Tags: web-services, exception, symfony, controller

I made a controller to provide some webservices in JSON and i would like to provide some errors informations when Symfony throw an exception ( Error 500 ) , how can i write such a thing ?

The main purpose of the webservice is to update informations in Symfony DB provided by the caller in POST values.

in my controller i return response in JSON and i would like to handle Symfony exception ( like when the values provided or not fitting the schema designed ) to return details informations about errors .

i thought about making a test of every values but it would be a long time to write and not e easy code to read or using a try / catch system , but i think Symfony already provide such a function .

What do you think ?

Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use an `EventListener` to catch errors and return the proper response.

You can place it inside your `SomethingBundle/EventListener` folder and also you need to define a `service` in order to be loaded by Symfony.

More info: [Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)

I hope I helped you, if you think I might be wrong, let me know. Good luck!

**EDIT**

If you only want to catch the errors inside a specific controller (for example) a controller called `Webservice` inside your `SomethingBundle`, you must check it before doing anything:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{       
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if($this->getBundle($request) == "Something" && $this->getController($request) == "Webservice")
    {
        // Do your magic
        //...
    }
}

private function getBundle(Request $request)
{
    $pattern = "#([a-zA-Z]*)Bundle#";
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($pattern, $request->get('_controller'), $matches);

    return (count($matches)) ? $matches[0] : null;
}

private function getController(Request $request)
{
    $pattern = "#Controller\\\([a-zA-Z]*)Controller#";
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($pattern, $request->get('_controller'), $matches);

    return (count($matches)) ? $matches[1] : null;
}
```

**DANGER** This code is not tested, is only an approach for you to build your own code. But, if I have something wrong on it, tell me. I'd like to keep my examples clean.

Comment: yes ! that's a good idea, but how can i use this eventlistener to catch exception only for my controller (my webservice controller )??

Comment: I did something similar months ago. Let me check my code and bring you an example. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonResponse` Symfony class in sandbox:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


$data = array(); // array of returned response, which encode to JSON
$data['error_message'] = 'Bad request or your other error...'); 

$response = new JsonResponse($data, 500); // 500 - response status
return $response;
```

Comment: it s not i was looking for, i was more after a function to detect exception throw by symfony without the exception template or simply detect when symfony throw an exception in order to return a bad status response.